Google Sheets - Create repeating sequence of numbers from 7-13
I am attempting to use Google Sheets (would rather use Excel but hey) to keep track of a task. I just want a slightly easier way to repeat the Numbers 7-13 in Column B from cell B3 onwards rather than having to type it out.
I tried adjusting this formula from a similar ask
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",", SEQUENCE(1,15)) & ",", ROUNDDOWN(ROWS(A1:A)/15)), ",")

into this
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",", SEQUENCE(7,13)) & ",", ROUNDDOWN(ROWS(B3:B)/7)), ",")

but google sheets did not like it.
Anyone got anything?

=arrayformula(mod(sequence(1000,1,0,1),7)+7) where 1000 is how many rows you want

You can use the SCAN function:
=SCAN(6,A3:A,LAMBDA(a,_,IF(a>12,7,a+1)))


